# How to use prepopulated_fields in Django w/o transliteration?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

prepopulated_fields in django admin.ModelAdmin autocomplete field title when I enter the name in django admin interface.

```
prepopulated_fields = {
    'title': ('name',),
}
```

How can I make the same functionality but without transliteration.

Ex:

```
name: Говядо
title: govyado
```

Want:

```
name: Говядо
title: Говядо
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

admin.py

```
class Media:
    js = ('/static/js/jquery.min.js',
          '/static/js/slug.js')
```

slug.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("id_name").onkeyup = function() {
      var e = document.getElementById("id_title");
      if (!e._changed) { e.value = document.getElementById("id_name").value; }
  }
}
```